# Expandable RecyclerView with Grid Layout Manager as child

Tags: gridview, android-recyclerview, expandable, recyclerview-layout

I want to have a RecyclerView which is foldable like expandable ListView and the children of each paren will present a GridView layout manager.

Is it possible? Can anyone direct me on how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full example [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example6Fragment.java) of how implement an Expandable GridView using this [library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter).

Basically you use the library to group your items into sections in order to have a header for each section but you can implement it [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/1401164).

Then you add a `GridLayoutManager`, define how many columns per row (2 in this example) and set the header to have a span size of 2 columns per row and children to have a span size of 1 column per row:

```
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
                case SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                    return 2;
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

In order to expand/collapse the sections, check the use of the `expanded` variable in the [example](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example6Fragment.java).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [example of Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/Armani2015/expandable-recyclerview-with-gridlayout) . It provides an Expandable RecyclerView with group items that can be individually expanded to show its children in a two-dimensional scrolling grid. Each grid item can be selected.

This how it works : Each ChildViewHolder object receives a data array from RecyclerView adapter to display in a grid row. Then it breaks up the layout of its row in rectangular cells of equal size. Each cell displays a piece of data.

Hope this will help anyone looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expandable RecyclerVew` and for children view use other `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view